# Underscore Js. conditional mapping

Tags: underscore.js

I have an object (oItem) which contains StartTime and EndTime (oItem below).

I am setting startTime1 and endTime1 of my view Model (oModelItem) to these, which works fine when all of the items have a 'sequence' property (not shown) of 00.

```
var oModelData = _.map(oResults, function(oItem) {
                        var oModelItem = {};

                        var nDayOfWeek = parseInt(oItem.DayOfWeek, 10);
                        oModelItem.BusinesDay = aDaysOfWeek[nDayOfWeek];
                        oModelItem.startTime1 = moment(oItem.StartTime.ms).format("HH:mm");
                        oModelItem.endTime1 = moment(oItem.EndTime.ms).format("HH:mm");
                        oModelItem.startTime2 = "";
                        oModelItem.endTime2 = "";
                        oModelItem.startDate = moment(oItem.StartDate).format("dddd, MMMM DD YYYY");
                        return oModelItem;
                    });
```

However, if there are any oitems with a sequence of '01',  I also need to set the startTime2 and endTime2, have first set startTime1 and endTime1 to the data from the otime with sequence '00'.

Where do I start with this? Each 00 oitem may or may not have a corresponding 01 oitem, but if it does, I need to create one single object which has startTime1 and endTime1 form the 00 sequence oitem and startTime2 and endTime2 from the 01 oitem (if it exists).

Comment: Can you post what oResults looks like and describe how items relate to each other?

Comment: {
    SequenceNumber:"00"
    StartTime: "09:00" 
    EndTime: "18:00"
    StartDate: "2016-01-20"
    },
    {
    SequenceNumber:"01"
    StartTime: "09:00"
    EndTime: "18:00"
    StartDate: "2016-01-20"
    },

Comment: So both items have startTime and endTime, but if the sequence is 00 the startTime and endTime needs to go to startTime1 and endTime1. However if there is an 01 sequence item, the startTime and endTime need to go to startTime2 and endTime2 of the same object......